# Can email be hosted on a different server than the website?

Tags: mx-record

While of course the answer in general is a resounding yes, this is my particular issue.

A person has a website "example.com" that is hosted unfortunately at hostgator. There email "@example.com" is hosted on that same server on hostgator which uses cpanel to manage the site and email.

The new website will be hosted on a separate robust and optimized DigitalOcean server. Normally, we would simply point the a record for example.com to point to the new server. The problem I see is that I imagine the email system would go down. Normally, if people use a third party service like Google Apps it's not a problem.

In this scenario however, is there anyway to point the website to the new server, but leave the email system intact on the previous server without having to have the 200+ people have to change any settings on their end? In the host gator DNS "example.com" and "webmail.example.com" and "mail.example.com" all point to the same ip. Theoretically, if I leave webmail and mail alone and just change "example.com" to point to the new server ip, the email should remain working exactly as before but with the website now be served at the new server? Or would the email stop working for reason? Any advice would be most helpful.

Comment: What does the MX record for the domain point to?

Comment: In the CPanel advanced DNS section it doesn't list any mx records. There is a separate section of Cpanel that says MX Records, and simply lists one line, "Priority: 0 : Destination: example.com"

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Right now email goes to wherever example.com resolves to. If you're going to change the example.com DNS record to resolve to the new web host then you'll want to change the MX record to be mail.example.com. That way after the change to example.com email will continue to flow to mail.example.com, which will remain unchanged. Do this now while they're both resolving to the same host. That way when you change the example.com DNS record there won't be any interruption in mailflow to example.com recipients.

Do the email clients connect to `mail.example.com` or `example.com`?

---

After all is said and done, this is whay you want:

example.com = new web host

www.example.com = new web host

mail.example.com = unchanged

webmail.example.com = unchanged

MX = mail.example.com

Answer (score 0):

What you said is correct. If you just change the A record pointing to the new IP, only the website pointing will be changed, taking into account that there is an existing MAIL.domain.com record and any Webmail CNAME's (if any).